# Redux thinks that a thunk is a reducer when being dispatched within a callback

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React/Redux application with thunk middleware installed and working propertly - all other thunk dispatches work fine. I have a thunk that is being dispatched along with a function handler that it itself needs to dispatch something.

Here is an example:

```
dispatch(triggerModal({
    payload: { key: 'value' },
    onClose: () => {
        dispatch(clearStuffAndCloseModal())
    }
}))
```

And in another file:

```
export const triggerModal = ({ payload, onClose }) => dispatch => {
    const data = await fetchSomeData(payload)
    // Do other random stuff.

    if (!data) {
        onClose()
    }
}

export const clearStuffAndCloseModal = () => dispatch => {
    console.log('start')

    dispatch(clearStuff()) // The error seems to be happening here as only 'start' is printed

    console.log('end')

    dispatch(closeModal())
}
```

When running this and triggering the `onClose`, I get an error in the browser console:

> redux.js:208  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Reducers may not dispatch
> actions

From what I can tell, it seems that Redux thinks that `clearStuffAndCloseModal` function is a reducer and gets upset when I'm trying to dispatch from a reducer. However, it's not a reducer but a thunk so I'm not quite sure how to fix this. I'm wondering if it's an issue with the dispatch call within the `onClose` callback.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any overt issue(s) with the action code specifically, but instead of passing a callback through the action payload to "chain" handlers/actions, I suggest the code should return the `data` value back to the caller and *then* dispatch the additional action(s) based on the result.

Example:

```js
export const triggerModal = (payload) => async (dispatch) => {
  const data = await fetchSomeData(payload);
  // Do other random stuff.

  return data;
};

export const clearStuffAndCloseModal = () => dispatch => {
  console.log('start');
  dispatch(clearStuff());
  console.log('end');
  dispatch(closeModal());
};
```

```js
const someFunction = async () => {
  const data = await dispatch(triggerModal({ key: 'value' }));

  if (!data) {
    dispatch(clearStuffAndCloseModal());
  }
};
```

or

```js
const someFunction = async () => {
  const data = await dispatch(triggerModal({ key: 'value' }));

  if (!data) {
    dispatch(clearStuff());
    dispatch(closeModal());
  }
};
```